# Insert statement within IF Exists using other data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple stored procedure that looks like so:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT tag, campaignID as campaignID
       FROM   Tags_Campaign_Watchlist
       WHERE  tag IN (SELECT *
                      FROM   dbo.splitstring (@tags)))
```

This returns the output of:

[image]

My goal is that during this statement for any matches it finds in the table, insert the campaign ID into another table called TableB, Just not sure how to make this happen during the check of each tag in the string it loops through.

**EDIT**

At the bottom of the statement where I do the insert, I need to pass to it the @lastID from the very first insert up top. Is this possible?

If i pass @tags = 'house,car,truck and the last inserts where 1,2,3 it will add the campaignID for house as well as 1, then the campaignID for car and 2 as the ID.

```
            AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Tags_Accounts (data, dataType, dataLocation, tag, whoAdded, whenAdded)
        SELECT @dbData,
               @dbDataType,
               @location,
               Name,
               @ntid,
               GETDATE()
        FROM   dbo.splitstring (@tags);

        DECLARE @lastID int
        SET @lastID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    END
END


--If one of the tags added is part of a campaign watchlist, add it to the watchlist data table.
IF EXISTS (SELECT tag, campaignID as campaignID
           FROM   Tags_Campaign_Watchlist
           WHERE  tag IN (SELECT *
                          FROM   dbo.splitstring (@tags)))

        BEGIN

            INSERT INTO Tags_Campaign_Watchlist_Data (campaignID, tagID)
            SELECT campaignID
            FROM   Tags_Campaign_Watchlist
                   WHERE  tag IN (SELECT *
                                  FROM   dbo.splitstring (@tags))

        END
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
DECLARE @tags VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @lastID int


SET @tags = 'bob,cat,carl,withdraw,awesome';
SET @lastID = '1';

BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT tag, campaignID as campaignID
       FROM   Tags_Campaign_Watchlist
       WHERE  tag IN (SELECT *
                      FROM   dbo.splitstring (@tags)))

        INSERT INTO Tags_Campaign_Watchlist_Data (campaignID, tagID)
        (SELECT campaignID, @lastID
        FROM   Tags_Campaign_Watchlist
               WHERE  tag IN (SELECT *
                              FROM   dbo.splitstring (@tags)))

    END
```

**This returns**

Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 14
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'tag', table 'local.dbo.Tags_Campaign_Watchlist_Data'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

I dont have the column TAG in watchlist data, jsut tagid and campaignID

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO TableB (campaignID)
SELECT campaignID 
FROM   Tags_Campaign_Watchlist
       WHERE  tag IN (SELECT *
                      FROM   dbo.splitstring (@tags))
```

**Update For Edit**

```
--If one of the tags added is part of a campaign watchlist, add it to the watchlist data table.
    IF EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   Tags_Campaign_Watchlist
               WHERE  tag IN (SELECT *
                              FROM   dbo.splitstring (@tags)))

            BEGIN

                INSERT INTO Tags_Campaign_Watchlist_Data (campaignID, tagID)
                SELECT campaignID, TagID
                FROM   Tags_Campaign_Watchlist
                       WHERE  tag IN (SELECT *
                                      FROM   dbo.splitstring (@tags))

            END
```

Comment: Made adjustment to original post to include the rest of the SP

Comment: @SBB in your Insert statement you only selected campaignID from table Tags_Campaign_Watchlist , all you needed was campaignID and also TagID in your select statement.

Comment: I tried that but it still didnt work .. Is it only getting the @lastID one time at the end or does it grab it for each insert?

Comment: The value you are assigning to your Tag variable, just do a simple select by passing that value to your IN operator with split function and see how many rows you get back.

Comment: @SBB you need to remove the Parenthesis around your SELECT statement, see my answer for that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41995/discussion-between-sbb-and-muhammed-ali)